# Get top item for each year

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, greatest-n-per-group

I have a datatable with some records. Using mysql I am able to get a result grouped by a specific period (year) and users and ordered (in descending order) by number of species.

```
SELECT YEAR(entry_date) AS period, uid AS user, COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS species
FROM records
WHERE YEAR(entry_date)<YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY period, uid
ORDER by period, species DESC
```

Please see attached [picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIjNp.png). But what if I only want the get the TOP USER (and number of species) for EACH year (the red marked rows)? How can I achieve that?

I am able to handle this later in my php code but it would be nice to have this sortered out already in mysql query.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Consider upgrading MySQL as MySQL 5.5 end of life was December 2018 unless you maintain the [Oracle's Lifetime Support policy](https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html). [Others](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/234266) including 5.6 runs through Feb 2021 and 5.7 through Oct 2023.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `RANK()` to rank records in years partitions by their count of species, and then filter on the top record per group:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(entry_date) AS period, 
        uid AS user, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS species,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(entry_date) ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT pid) DESC) rn
    FROM records
    WHERE entry_date < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-01-01')
    GROUP BY period, uid
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER by period
```

This preserves top ties, if any. Note that uses an index-friendly filter on the dates in the `WHERE` clause.

In earlier versions, an equivalent option is to filter with a `HAVING` clause and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(entry_date) AS period, 
    uid AS user, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS species
FROM records r
WHERE entry_date < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-01-01')
GROUP BY period, uid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pid) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r1.pid) species1
    FROM records r1
    WHERE YEAR(r1.entry_date) = period
    GROUP BY r1.uid
    ORDER BY species1 DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER by period
```

Comment: And what if not? This does not seem to work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MichalStružský: which version of MySQL are you running? `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: version 5.5.62-38.14

Comment: But the version using HAVING has a  ROW_NUMBER()  as well. Can I get rid of it completely? My version does not seem to know that. (Syntax error near '(PARTITION BY YEAR(entry_date) ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT pid) DESC) rn FROM recor' at line 5)

Comment: @MichalStružský: I just (finished) providing a solution for earlier version (without `ROW_NUMBER()`, which was hanging in there due to bad copy/past).

Comment: Unfortunately, no rows returned. :(

Comment: I adjusted the query to fit my database (it uses czech table names) and the year condition and this query gives me only the top row for 2020.


`SELECT 
    YEAR(datum) AS period, 
    uid AS user, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS species
FROM _zaznamy r
WHERE YEAR(datum) <= 2020
GROUP BY period, uid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pid) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r1.pid) species1
    FROM _zaznamy r1
    WHERE YEAR(r1.datum) = YEAR(r.datum)
    GROUP BY r1.uid
    ORDER BY species1 DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER by period`

Comment: @MichalStružský: this should work... Can you provide a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with sample data so we can test the query?

Comment: Sure, here you go. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=331adadc7fa97df65abb26b86a2ccb6b (It should return uid 2017 | uid 22 | 5; 2018 | uid106 | 5; 2019 | uid106 | 6 if I am not mistaken)

Comment: @MichalStružský: I slightly updated the query, this seems to work fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c003267ef713a2efcbb011cb84b15268